# Creating random Image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, random

The final input of my work will be quintile `ee.Image` objects. To test my display I would like to create an `ee.Image` with the value in each pixel set randomly in [1, 5] (only integer).

I have already an `ee.Image` that could be used as a base:

```
var data = ee.Image('Oxford/MAP/accessibility_to_cities_2015_v1_0')
```

I just want to rewrite every pixel in it.

Is there a simple way to do that in Google Earth Engine ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a random image with `ee.Image.random()`. It will be between 0 and 1. To convert it to ints between 1 and 5, you can do this:

```
ee.Image.random().multiply(5).add(1).byte()
```

If you want to use the same mask as your `data` image, you can do this:

```
var image = ee.Image.random().multiply(5).add(1).byte()
  .updateMask(data.mask())
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/fbbe60d68bff6883556034bffbffcdc2